# Opamp - find current coming to the noninverting input - the basics

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current

[image]

In the picture there is an inverting opamp, so the equation for gain is:

$$ A_{CL} =\dfrac{-R2}{R1} $$
How can I find: $$U_⊕ , U_⊖, U_{wy}$$

How can I find the current (I)? (see picture)

What rules should I use?

Comment: This is very basic op-amp theory. Assuming it's an ideal op-amp, (1) what do you know about the characteristics of the inputs? (2) Given that it's an inverting configuration what do you know about the steady-state input voltages?

Comment: Ahem, that's a non-inverting op-amp circuit.

Comment: Yup, non-inverting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this is a non-inverting amplifier configuration; however, that I believe was mentioned in the comments below the question post.

If you are treating this as an ideal op amp, the *virtual short* approximation works pretty well here. The virtual short approximation states that the voltage at the inverting and noninverting terminals are equal. Additionally, in an ideal op amp, no current flows into these terminals; thus, I is zero. Here, you can just do your favorite circuit analysis technique to determine the voltages by setting \$U_{+}\$ and \$U_{-}\$ equal to each other, and find the output voltage \$U_{wy}\$. You have an ideal gain formula, so the output voltage \$U_{wy}\$ is the input voltage times that gain. The gain for the ideal noninverting amplifier is
$$
G = 1 + \frac{R_{f}}{R_{1}}
$$
Where \$R_{f}\$ is your feedback resistance and \$R_{1}\$ is the resistance connecting the negative terminal to ground.

Since the information here is limited, I doubt this is a basic non-ideal op amp problem. But if it was, you would have to define and determine a large resistance to model input bias currents between inverting and noninverting terminals. Furthermore, a small resistance to model output bias current. Also, you would have to determine the output gain to the difference in inverting and non-inverting terminals \$A_{0}\$. Having these three things allow you to properly find the current I and voltages listed. For the ideal case, you let \$A_{0}, r_{in}\$ approach infinity and \$r_{out}\$ approach 0.

I attached a figure below from the textbook *Microelectronics Circuits and Devices*, 2nd ed. by Mark N. Horenstein, published in 1996 from Pearson Education Inc. The figure can be seen on page 39 in chapter 2.
[image]